# images suddenly don't show on website

Tags: html, css, image

I was working on this website when suddenly the server stopped displaying images on HTML. The image paths work alone and there wasn't any change to the server or website when this happened.

Here's the url : http://test.filipematias.info/filipepinto/comunidadeeambiente.html

Any ideas to traceback the problem?

Comment: here I can see too. at least you'll get some pageviews ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the images clearly. Maybe it's cache or you have other problems with the browser? Try using a different browser or clear your cache.

Comment: I asked some friends to open the website and it still didn't worked. Maybe it's cached at the ISP somehow.

Comment: That might be it indeed. I see a black image on the left, correct? Or are there more images?

Comment: Most of the websites are images, but that one exists yes.

Answer (score 0):

I also see images. try different browsers, or from different device.

if you want to explorer the problem a little further, try using the browser's console (F12 on chrome/firefox) - you can find there warnings, network problems ect' and you can also inspect the elements with the inspector. so if you see a broken image you can inspect it in the code and try to figure out what went wrong.

anyway, nice design!

and you have few broken URLs... :)